# can't remove records in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm trying to remove all the records in my mongodb collection. But when I check to see if it is empty all the records are still there.

```
var database = mongoose.connect('localhost','news');
Article.find(function(err,articles){
    Article.remove(articles);
});

Article.find(function(err,articles){
    if(!err){
        console.log(articles);
    }else{
        console.log(err);
    }
})
console.log(database);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because [`remove`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.remove) takes a query conditions object, not the list of documents to remove.  You also need to put your `find` inside your `remove` callback or it will be executed before the `remove` completes.

Try this instead:

```
Article.remove({}, function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        Article.find(function(err,articles){
            if(!err){
                console.log(articles);
            }else{
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
});
```